# PHP - How to get week of year without leading zero?

Tags: php, date, format

echo date('W');

It gives me `"06"`, but I only want 6, instead of 06. Is there a way to get the week of year in single character if the week is less than 10. I have couple of ways to deal with this, like:

- Check if week is less than 10, then use substring.
- etc..

Is there any more convenient way?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Couldn't you just convert it into a int using `intval()`.

Answer (score 4):

```
settype($week = date('W'), 'int');
$week = (int) date('W');
$week = intval(date('W'));
//and my favorite
$week = date('W')+0;
```

i believe there is no other method left, correct me if you got another, i made this wiki.